# Sending parameter back to controller from view to download a file

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to send a parameter to my controller to download a file. However it only works when hardcoded, I seem to be unable to assign it with a variable.

'''

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("GetFiles", "Home", new { EventID = 57 })">Download Form</a>
```

Is there a way for me to set the value of EventID to a form value or Viewbag value. At the moment the only value I can set it to is a physcial integer eg. 57. This will change dependent on which event I am in, at which point I can set this value inside the javascript.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetFiles(int eventId)
{
    //ViewData["eventID"] = eventId;

    using (MyDatabaseEntities1 dc = new MyDatabaseEntities1())
    {
        var sc = dc.ScanReports.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EventID == eventId);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/reports/"), sc.FileName + sc.FileExtension);
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, sc.FileName);
    }
}
```

Updated - Added eventID into form

````
  <form id="download" action="@Url.Action("GetFiles", "Home")" method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="EventID" id="reportEventID" /><br />
        <button>Download Report</button>
  </form>

Ajax Call
``` 
```
$('#download').submit(function (e) {
  $.ajax({
      url: this.action,
      type: this.method,
      data: new FormData(this),
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function () {
      $('#myModalReport').modal('hide');
      },

    });
});
````

Comment: you can call the action dynamically via javascript where youll be able to pass any dynamic value in that you need to, assuming all of the eventids that you need exist on the dom somewhere. the specific implementation of this depends on how youre view/markup is structured which you havent shown

Comment: Can you please share the line of code where you are passing the parameter dynamically?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help, I have created a form instead and passed these values to ajax request